# PHP 5.3+ does not support lambdas?

Tags: php, class, lambda

Does PHP actually have support for [lambdas](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)?

```
<?php

class ExampleClass
{
    public $variable = array(
        "example"   =>  function( $str )
        {
            return str_replace("a","-",$str);
        }
    );
}
?>
```

The error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION) in /var/www/test.php on line 6

I know I can use [`create_function`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php), but I hate it...

Comment: Maybe it's the class context - does it work to create it in the constructor?

Comment: This question can be answered by looking at [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is much simpler - you cannot initialize class properties using complex expressions. You can set it to constant value, but not function call, function creation or so.

Look here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Further explanation - this code won't work because you're trying to initialize `variable` property using anonymous function:

```
<?php
class ExampleClass
    {
    // fails because of complex expression
    public $variable = array(
        "example" => function($str) { return str_replace("a", "-", $str); }
        );
    }
```

If you want that property to hold function handle, change your code as follows:

```
<?php
class ExampleClass
    {
    // might be left uninitialized as well
    public $variable = null;

    public function __construct()
        {
        // now object context is initialized
        // so you can perform complex actions on it
        $this->variable = array(
            "example" => function($str) { return str_replace("a", "-", $str); }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, what I have in mind, but would like to know why PHP does not work as I want

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detailed info.

Comment: @OlafErlandsen I agree it is annoying that what you want does not work, the reasons for it are many and varied, they are all related to the way PHP works internally, and a full discussion of them is really outside the scope of StackOverflow. It would theoretically be possible to implement a limited amount of what you want (notably, `use()` would not be possible, mostly because it wouldn't make any sense) but it's unlikely to happen in the near future.